# Prime with digits reversed is prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Well, just another idea came up into my mind and i have no idea how to solve it :D
Is there infinitely many prime numbers, which are not repunits and their inverse is also prime? (For example, inverse of 31 is 13 which is also prime. i didn't have any other name to describe the function!)
P.S:I now know they are called [Emirp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emirp)s.

Comment: are reverse ordered prime numbers, e.g., $31\rightarrow 13$, which are still prime, are infinitely many?

Comment: Do you allow palindromic primes? It is conjectured, but not proven, that there are infinitely many repunit primes (eg 11).

Comment: look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emirp

Comment: and for repunit I suggest http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repunit

Comment: well i bet i should say that they are not repunits.

Comment: 13 and 31 are emirp (decimal notation).  But D and 1F are not emirp (hexadecimal notation).  It seems a strange question to me.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Actually, it has a name and it's quaintly called an "*[emirp](http://oeis.org/A006567)*". (The word "*prime*" in reverse.)  The link given is to the *Online Encyclopaedia of Integers*' list,

$13, 17, 31, 37, 71, 73, 79, 97, 107, 113, 149, 157, 167,\dots$

While there are an infinite number of primes, I believe it is an open problem if there is an infinite number of emirps.

P.S. Regarding terminology, given $x$, then its "*multiplicative inverse*" (or "*reciprocal*") is $1/x$. For functions, for ex, given $\sin(x)$, then its "*inverse function*" is $\arcsin(x)$.

Comment: Confusingly, in French it's the other way around; the "réciproque" of $\sin(x)$ is $\arcsin(x)$, and "l'invers" of $\sin(x)$ is $\csc(x)$.

Comment: Ah, some things get lost in translation, do they?  :)